# Asymptotic convergence of ODE solutions to a unique function, regardless of initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics

I have a non-linear differential equation of the form

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=F(x) - G(y,x)
$$

where $G$ is of the form

$$
G(y,x) = y^3f_3(x)-y^2f_2(x)
$$
and $f_2,f_3>0$ for all $x$, and $F(x)>0$ for all $x$.

Below I attach results from numerical integration for different initial conditions (the integration is backwards from $x=3$ to $x=0$), indicated by the colored lines.
It seems that regardless of the initial condition, the solutions seem to be asymptotic to a unique function.

Is there a general statement I can use to prove this result? Namely, what conditions do $F,G$ need to satisfy in order for solutions to be asymptotic to a unique function, regardless of the initial conditions?

Furthermore, it seems that a good approximation for this asymptotic behavior is given by the solution to the equation (shown as the black dashed line)
$$
G(y,x)=F(x)
$$

which one gets if he sets $dy/dx=0$ in the above equation (which, of course, is not true). How can one explain this?

[image: numerical solution]

Answer (score 4):

If the rate of change of the $f_k$ coefficient functions is small enough, relative to their values, or the $y$-derivative close to the root of the polynomial, then you can set $x$ as constant and apply the rules of an autonomous scalar dynamical system.

Close to the roots (as long as they are simple) the solution either moves to them or away from them exponentially. If far away from the roots, the solution changes fast in vertical direction towards one of the roots, as you can see in your initial segment from $3.0$ to $2.8$. As the coefficients change "adiabatically", the solution will follow that change, lagging in time. This is what you observe moving from $2.8$ to the left, with the solution slightly below the root curve.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you perhaps have a reference regarding these points so I can read more about them?

Comment: No, not really. While I remember reading about such asymptotics, I do not know where. More recently I had more experience doing practical experiments. Some books discuss examples like $y'=x^2-y^2$ or $y'=x-y^2$ in detail. In books or chapters on perturbation theory this situation might be abstracted as $y'=f(\varepsilon x,y)$ with $0<\varepsilon\ll 1$. A similar topic occurs in fast-slow systems, the canard system or VanderPol oscillator with a large parameter is one guiding example.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, this was a really good comment! It's like, under some conditions, we can think in the non-autonomous system as a family of autonomous systems parameterized by $x$. And for each $x$ we have a stable equilibrium $y_0$ that are different points in an non-constant attracting solution. Is this right? 
Could you cite any of these books you refer in "Some books discuss examples like"?